# Adobe Services API - need Authorize URI and Token URI

Tags: oauth-2.0, adobe

I am trying to set up an orchestration app that I'm using (Make.com) to connect to the Adobe PDF Services API. The first step is to set up the OAuth 2.0 connection which requires information that I just can't find anywhere.

Adobe has given me the Client ID and Client Secret, but I need to enter the Authorize URI and Token URI to complete the connection.

Does anyone know where I can find this?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gx1kD.png)

Hours of surfing and hunting around with no luck :-(

Answer (score 0):

is this what you are looking for?:

https://developer.adobe.com/developer-console/docs/guides/authentication/UserAuthentication/IMS/#fetching-access-tokens

```
https://ims-na1.adobelogin.com/ims/authorize/v2
  ?client_id={CLIENT_ID}
  &redirect_uri={REDIRECT_URI}
  &scope={SCOPES}
  &state={STATE}
  &response_type=code
```

Question to you. How/where did you get the client secret? I;m not able to find in anywhere...